# MinionPro and Searchability/Encoding

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste, minionpro

I'm using pdflatex with the MinionPro package. The PDF looks fine, but apparently some characters (specifically "W" and the "Th" ligature) are put in the PDF in a way that breaks searchability. For example, if a document contains the text "A Wedge", then searching for "A Wedge" will not yield a hit. If I copy and paste this string into a text file, the result is "AWedge". With "Th" it's similar: "A Thing" becomes "AThing" when copied into a text file.

As mentioned in the MinonPro manual, I'm using

```
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

but this doesn't solve the problem. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
A Wedge A Thing
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a ligature problem: you pdf reader doesn't recognize the spaces as they are rather small. You will have to enlarge the interword spacing.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I think it would be sufficient to increase the interword spacing before "W" and "Th". Apparently with microtype and \SetExtraSpacing it's possible to define the interword spacing _after_ a given character, but what I need is to change the spacing _before_ a given character. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, and Ulrike's comment was the key for that (thanks again!) As she pointed out, the spaces before "W" and "Th" were too small for the Adobe Reader to be detected as spaces. Ulrike suggested to increase the interword spacing.

However instead of increasing the interword spacing in general, it struck me as a better solution to only change the spaces where it is actually needed (i.e., before "W" and "Th"), and I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\SetExtraKerning[context=extended,unit=space]
{encoding={*}, family={MinionPro-OsF}, series={*}, size={normalsize}}
{W={70,},
 T={180,}}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
Original kerning:

A Wedge A Thing

Adapted kerning:

\begin{microtypecontext}{kerning=extended}
A Wedge A Thing
\end{microtypecontext}

\end{document}
```

When I copy the text of the resulting PDF document and paste it in a text file, the result is as follows:

```
Original kerning:
AWedge AThing
Adapted kerning:
A Wedge A Thing
```

Comment: If your output really looks like that without modification, I would say there is something wrong somewhere - either in your set up or in the packages you are using or something. Are you sure you are using the correct Minion support package for the version of Minion Pro you have installed for TeX? Note that there are a number of different packages optimised for different versions of the fonts and it matters that you match them. When I process the code in your question, for example, I have no problems copy and pasting.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks. It's quite interesting that you don't experience that problem. Are you also using MinionPro v2.1 and did you copy from Adobe Reader? I recreated all MinionPro related files following the [readme](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/README), and the problem still occurs. However, I noted a small discrepancy: The readme mentions the otfinfo output "Version 2.012;PS 002.000;Core 1.0.38;makeotf.lib1.6.6565", whereas it says "Version 2.015;PS 002.000;Core 1.0.38;makeotf.lib1.7.9032" for my files. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: `Version 2.068;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.57;makeotf.lib2.0.21895` Oh, and, yes, these are from Reader.

Comment: As far as I remember. I've certainly never purchased them. There is a slim chance they might be from an old version of Acrobat I used to use if I copied them from my Mac along with the rest of my TeX stuff. But I'm pretty sure they are from Reader (either for Mac or for Linux).

Comment: @cfr: My OTF files also came with the Adobe Reader. Do you use the package from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) or [this fork](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro)?

Comment: CTAN. That's not enough characters!

Comment: I found another version of the OTF files on my system (`Version 2.103;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.67;makeotf.lib2.5.29150`) and used those. The problem still occurs ...

Comment: Sorry. I don't really know what to say. Unless it is a difference between PDF viewers? I was using Okular.

Comment: This could indeed make the difference. Actually it occurred to me before that it might depend on the PDF viewer. That was what I meant when I asked "did you copy from Adobe Reader?" Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Oh, sorry! I thought you meant did I copy the *fonts* from Adobe Reader. I guess because it was in the same sentence as the query about the version...

Comment: I can confirm it is a rendering bug in Adobe Reader. I see the same problem if I open the PDF in `acroread` but there's no problem with Okular.